# Refresh a frame from a form in delphi

Tags: delphi

I add a frame to a vcl form and link a frame to that frame. in the form i call to a function which is in the frame to view data in a grid. the function is working correctly. grid is not showing any change. there is a another button in the frame which is call to same function, when i click that one its working. how can i do this?

This code is in the form

```
procedure TMainF.RefrshFramebtnClick(Sender: TObject);
var PatientHistoryFr: TPatientHistoryFr;
begin
  PatientHistoryFr := TPatientHistoryFr.Create(Application);
  PatientHistoryFr.RefreshGrid;
  PatientHistoryFr.Free; 
end;
```

This code is in the frame(TPatientHistoryFr is the frame)

```
procedure TPatientHistoryFr.RefreshGrid;
begin
  if HistoryQr.Active then
    HistoryQr.Close;
  HistoryQr.SQL.Text := 'select * from doctor';
  HistoryQr.Open;
end;
```

Not Working:

[image: click the button in the form(not working)]

Working:

[image: click the button in the frame(working)]

Comment: So how many frames do you have here? One which frame does the grid reside; the first or second? On which is the RefreshGrid; the first or the second?

Comment: two. first one is in a different unit. second one is showing the first frame.

Comment: Now which one is PatientHistoryFr? The first or second? Before you answer me via comment; edit your question to reflect that so everyone will know which is which.

Comment: Why do you make frame owned by Application? Frames should be owned by form. Make it this way `PatientHistoryFr := TPatientHistoryFr.Create(Self);`

Comment: Also, some grid components already have their own `RefreshGrid` method. Try using another name. This one is too generic anyway. Good practice is to use names that explain what it does, not how it does it.

Comment: @quasoft: " that explain what it does, not how it does it" Maybe, but there could hardly be a clearer description of what it does than "RefreshGrid", could there?

Comment: @Blurry TPatientHistoryFr is the first frame. second one is used to link the first frame. then its not in the code. link in the design. Thanks.

Comment: @quasoft, Its not working. i already tried. Thanks.

Comment: As I said; edit your question and update it with the relevant info

Comment: @MartynA I personally would name the method `ReloadDoctors()`. The fact that information is visualized with a grid is not relevant. In a month they could decide to change it with a ListView, or embeded HTML browser, or anything. Plus, in VCL and Win32, refresh action is related to updating canvas of controls on screen. When I see the name `RefreshGrid` without looking at code, I could decide it is used after invalidation of canvas.

Comment: @quasoft:  If that's your preference, fine.  Personally I think a descriptive name for the frame should suffice, but ymmv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its just simple.

```
FrameHistory.RefreshGrid;
```

thats all. FrameHistory is the frame which is on the frame. Thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You are freeing PatientHistoryFr immediately after calling its RefreshGrid in the very same procedure. When do you expect it to show anything if it has been destroyed?

Comment: I removed the freeing PatientHistoryFr line. but still not working.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand, what do You want.
First of all, this line:

```
PatientHistoryFr := TPatientHistoryFr.Create(Self);
```

only create a frame, but while frame does not have parent - it is NOT visible.
Add this line:

```
PatientHistoryFr.Parent := Self;
```

This will show the frame. And then call

```
PatientHistoryFr.RefreshGrid;
```

Good luck:)

Comment: Thanks Aleksandr This creating create another frame. otherwise its working. I want refresh the frame in the form.